# Python external on Azure ImportError No Module Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

If i locally run my code with python main.py, then this error occurs locally. If i run it with python3 main.py, it works as expected. I suspect my azure app service is not running the correct version of python, however, it is set to python 3.4

```
    StdErr: 
2018-06-30 19:47:13.785205: Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = handler()
  File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 120, in get_venv_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))
  File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 89, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "main.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 73, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from newspaper import Article
ImportError: No module named 'newspaper'
```

UPDATE

So I went to the debug console in kudo and i ran python 
`-m pip install --upgrade -r d:\home\site\wwwroot\requirements.txt`.

Here is the error

```
 ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n" ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed ** Using build configuration of libxslt
```

One of the requirements is Pillow which requires libxml2 and libxslt. I've tried using wheels however, I've had no success.

UPDATE II
I tried to install virtualenv since it does not exist and I receive a permissions error.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE III
I ran this command

```
D:\home\python364x64>python -m pip install newspaper3k
```

I test everything locally, and it works perfect. I push and receive this error below.

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\home\python364x64\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\home\python364x64\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "D:\home\python364x64\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from newspaper import Article
  File "D:\home\python364x64\lib\site-packages\newspaper\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .api import (build, build_article, fulltext, hot, languages,
  File "D:\home\python364x64\lib\site-packages\newspaper\api.py", line 12, in <module>
    import feedparser
  File "D:\home\python364x64\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 316
    raise KeyError, "object doesn't have key 'category'"
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Comment: did you install using pip install newspaper3k ?

Comment: I installed using pip3 install newspaper3k

Comment: still getting the errror?

Comment: When I run it locally, installing all of my external libraries using pip3 install xxxx then run with python3 main.py it works. When I deploy to azure, it fails. the log above is then displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure you hit exactly my error, but I solved it like this: https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/install-python-modules.md Basically create a Venv in your webapp site folder, add it to path inside you code and import modules.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: yeah, read the link I've provided, you need to create venv, install all the packages into the venv, import venv into the path and them import modules. last two steps should be done inside python script

Comment: See my update. I cannot implement your solution until i figure out how to install virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, we have no permission to modify `D:\home` environment.

So , It's better to use python extension. Please follow the steps in this case: [Azure Flask Routes Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143378/azure-flask-routes-not-found/51145599?noredirect=1#comment89338529_51145599) and use command `python -m pip install newspaper` to install additional packages in python extension.

Please make sure the package you want to install must match with version of python extension. Otherwise, it will throw error as follows.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey Jay please see my update. I think we are close to the answer but not quite there yet.

Comment: Please see this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197607/newspaper3k-syntax-error-or-wrong-python-version?noredirect=1#comment89377077_51197607