# Azure Flask Routes Not found

Tags: python, azure, flask, deployment

I am using visual studio to create a blank Flask app. When I run the application locally, I get the expected "hello world". When I publish to Azure App Service, I get this nice ugly blue home page that I didn't make. No where in my project does this code exist, atleast that I can see in visual studio solution explorer. If I try to nagivate to `<my account name>.azurewebsites.net/test` I get a `404` error. Any suggestion?

[image]

***app.py:***

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Make the WSGI interface available at the top level so wfastcgi can get it.
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

@app.route('/test')
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Renders a sample page."""
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

***web deploy.pubxml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/78439574-998e-4216-b54c-40fa45d65ca5/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/FlaskWebProject220180702122411</ResourceId>
    <ResourceGroup>Default-SQL-EastUS</ResourceGroup>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://flaskwebproject220180702122411.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>flaskwebproject220180702122411.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>FlaskWebProject220180702122411</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>$FlaskWebProject220180702122411</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <_DestinationType>AzureWebSite</_DestinationType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

UPDATE:

I followed the steps listed by Jay. I am now getting a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". I added a log file in the application setting, however, it does not appear.

[image]

[image]

UPDAtE 2

I noticed that in my  from web.config the versions were different so i updated it. this allowed the logs.txt to be created.

```
  <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
```

I am still getting a 500 error.

logs.txt:
[image]

Comment: whats in the logs? use this to enable them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/07/14/troubleshoot-logging-python-application-errors-on-azure-webapi-apps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to my work steps and see if the error still shows up.

Step 1 : Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.1 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you deploy successfully, you could see following structure in the `KUDU` path: `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`.

[image]

If you want to use additional python package, please go on.

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install pyodbc`

[image]

Hope it helps you. Any concern ,please let me know.

---

***Update***:

In my steps, copy content in `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` to install pip. It could identify the system python version, install the corresponding python package.

[image]

So,you just need to run the command `python -m pip install newspaper3k` to install `newspaper3k`.

[image]

Comment: I updated my question. It seems that i no longer get the blue screen but I do get an error message. Even though it still works locally.

Comment: @EK_AllDay Based on your error, it should be internal 500 error. Have you checked log on kudu?

Comment: i updated my question with logs. We are getting close to a solution

Comment: @EK_AllDay let's chat in this room:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174213/pythonflask

Comment: Okay I messaged you.

Comment: does this handle pip3?

Comment: @EK_AllDay If you follow my steps, pip will automatically recognize the python version.

Comment: I followed your steps and I tried to install newspaper3k and it throwing errors. I thought maybe it was a version issue with pip.

Comment: @EK_AllDay Hi, are you referring to this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118110/python-external-on-azure-importerror-no-module-found